# Why my partial won't receive parameters correctly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, view

When rendering a partial called 'member', it says error

> undefined local variable or method `user' for #<#:0x000000095ec8c0>

Why??

My codes are

**View**

```
<% @users.each do |user| %>  
    <%= render 'member', :locals => {:user => user} %>      
<% end %>
```

**Partial**

```
<div class="chapter">
  <p class="title">
    <%= user.user_profile.nickname %>(<%= user.username %>)
  </p>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use:

```
<%= render :partial => 'member', :locals => { :user => user } %>
```

Or just with:

```
<%= render 'member', :user => user %>
```

Answer (score 3):

My advice is that you stick to the conventions whenever you can; everything will go a lot smoother for you if you do.

If you had a `_user.html.erb` partial, you could be using this rails convention

```
<% @users.each do |user| %>
 <%= render user %>
<% end %>
```

But you can even shorten this more

```
<%= render @users %>
```

Huzzah!

I strongly suggest you check out the [Layouts and Rendering Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html)